What does this red double headed arrow mean in eclipse
What does this red icon mean? I am guessing it is coming from an extension as it isn't shown in any of the eclipse help, and doesn't have a hover over.
This is package explorer


These are merge conflicts. Which versioning system do you use for this project?

It is a merge conflict as kindly pointed out by @howlger

